# how to handle identify scrollbar is disabled or not present

Tags: java, selenium, scroll

how to handle identify scrollbar is disabled or not present

I tried to find the xpath for scrollbar to check if it is there. But as there were not more elements in frame so scrollbar was disabled or not available.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

you can run following code:

```
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Boolean isScroll = (Boolean) (jsExec.executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;"));
```

Important part is JavaScript code that check height of browser.

Full code:

```
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.get("https://selenium.dev");
JavascriptExecutor jsExec = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
Boolean isScroll = (Boolean) (jsExec
        .executeScript("return document.documentElement.scrollHeight>document.documentElement.clientHeight;"));
if (isScroll == true) {
    System.out.print("Scrollbar is exist.");
} else if (isScroll == false) {
    System.out.print("Scrollbar is not exist.");
}
driver.quit();
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit which element you are referring as `documentElement`?

Comment: it is JavaScript code that document is referring webpage in JS. scrollHeight getting the size of page, height and calculates full size document and compares them.

Comment: `document` -> `webpage` and others mentioned is fine. But what is `documentElement`? I don't see you defining it.